# Columns are concatenated in R package data

Tags: r, csv, package, devtools, rda

I have a CSV file called `startdates.csv` which I want to provide to colleagues as part of an R package called `tabulations`. The individual steps work during development but when the package is installed and loaded, the data.frame columns are concatenated. Here are the details:

As per [Hadley Wickham's excellent book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html) and [this very helpful summary](http://www.davekleinschmidt.com/r-packages/), I put `startdates.csv` in `data-raw/`, and ran the following script to save it as `data/startdates.rda`:

```r
startdates <- read.csv("data-raw/startdates.csv")
devtools::use_data(startdates, overwrite=T)
```

which works as expected:

```r
> source("data-raw/get_tabs.r")
Saving startdates as startdates.rda to /home/matthewroberts7/ieTabs/tabulations/data
> startdates
  Dataset Observations Potential_start_date_fields  Earliest    Latest Missing
1   jeval      6445712                           5 30NOV2000 21NOV****   0.04%
2   jhist      7058169                           5 12MAY2001 17SEP****   2.90%
3   ueval       390783                           5 29APR2013 29JUN2016   0.00%
```

During development, all is well:

```r
> setwd("tabulations")
> devtools::load_all()
Loading tabulations
> tabulations::startdates
  Dataset Observations Potential_start_date_fields  Earliest    Latest Missing
1   jeval      6445712                           5 30NOV2000 21NOV****   0.04%
2   jhist      7058169                           5 12MAY2001 17SEP****   2.90%
3   ueval       390783                           5 29APR2013 29JUN2016   0.00%
```

But when the package is installed it's as if the original csv has been saved as a single string per row:

```r
> setwd("..")
> document("tabulations")
Updating tabulations documentation
Loading tabulations
> install("tabulations")
Installing tabulations
...
> reload(inst("tabulations"))
Reloading installed tabulations
> tabulations::startdates
  Dataset.Observations.Potential_start_date_fields.Earliest.Latest.Missing
1                                jeval,6445712,5,30NOV2000,21NOV****,0.04%
2                                jhist,7058169,5,12MAY2001,17SEP****,2.90%
3                                 ueval,390783,5,29APR2013,29JUN2016,0.00%
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here? Many thanks.

EDIT: R v3.4.2, devtools v1.13.4